# Send special character Requests Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to send a files with the POST HTTP protocole.

Ma file is a torrent file and I use this to send http://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html

Here my code

```
m = MultipartEncoder(
      fields={
            'torrent': ('torrent', open('mytest.torrent', 'r'), 'application/x-bittorrent'), 
            'name': str.encode('myname')
      }
)
u = request.post(uploadUrl, data=m, headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
print(u.text)
print(u.headers)
print(u)
```

but nothing I have this error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 366: invalid start byte

What should I do ? thanks

Comment: `open("mytest.torrent", "rb")`.

Comment: Same UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 366: invalid start byte

Comment: Nobody have an idea ?